# Can't prevent a DOM element from being painted using an extension contentscript with runAt document_start

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to insert some css and JS with an extension to prevent a DOM element from being painted onto the screen

I have tried `webNavigation.onCommitted` event and injecting css/js as well as `contentScripts.register` (w/ polyfill for chrome) with `runAt: "document_start"`

My code is definitely running, just too slow and the DOM element in question flashes into and out of existence.

Thank you

Comment: This is definitely a problem that needs a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve) because usually it just works, here's a [random example](/a/39618852). I suggest switching to the native content_scripts declaration instead of polyfills or use chrome.declarativeContent directly with RequestContentScript action which works in stable Chrome despite the warning in the documentation.

Comment: I just did a test and

- a 1 line id selector contentscript css caused no flash
- a 10 line nested children selector contentscript css caused a flash

that makes intuitive sense if the selector doesn't match until more DOM elements are added onto the page.